# Dynamic Array, taking data from select

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that has this structure:

```
array (size=6)
  0 => 
    array (size=9)
      0 => string 'Dorado' (length=6)
      1 => string '32GB' (length=4)
      2 => string 'Plastico' (length=8)
      'vlr' => string '40000' (length=5)
      'pcost' => string '0' (length=1)
      'pcomp' => string '0' (length=1)
      'sede' => 
        array (size=1)
          9 => string '0' (length=1)
      'ptc' => 
        array (size=2)
          12 => string '0' (length=1)
          11 => string '0' (length=1)
      's' => string '' (length=0)
  1 => 
    array (size=9)
      0 => string 'Dorado' (length=6)
      1 => string '32GB' (length=4)
      2 => string 'Madera' (length=6)
      'vlr' => string '40000' (length=5)
      'pcost' => string '0' (length=1)
      'pcomp' => string '0' (length=1)
      'sede' => 
        array (size=1)
          9 => string '0' (length=1)
      'ptc' => 
        array (size=2)
          12 => string '0' (length=1)
          11 => string '0' (length=1)
      's' => string '' (length=0)
```

I have values from a selection that is Dorado->32GB->Madera and I need find this value in the array; if its true that it exists, then take the other values like a vlr, pcost, etc.

What is the best method to find that, remembering that the values with number are dynamic, sometimes with 1 or 5 example:

```
0 => string 'Dorado' (length=6)
      1 => string '32GB' (length=4)
      2 => string 'Plastico' (length=8)
```

```
0 => string 'Azul' (length=6)
      1 => string '32GB' (length=4)
```

Can somebody explain how I could do this?

Comment: Not really clear what you want - take only numeric keys (0,1,2 and more) from every subarray?

Comment: Hello, @u_mulder i have different selects with strings, i take that in ajax and pass them to PHP, i have different products names and variables with that structure, i need search in this array from every subarray but it found all variables correct, comparing with strings that had send me a true message.

Comment: http://tupyme.tk/jkmobile/iphone-x its a example

Comment: `array_intersect_assoc` can help to check the “overlap” between one of your data array items, and your search array. If that intersection contains the same elements under the same keys, as your search array did (simply comparison with `==`), then you have found an item that matches all your search criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose, this is a code to start with:

```
$searchValue1 = 'Dorado';
$searchValue2 = '32GB';
$searchValue3 = 'Plastico';

foreach ($yourArray as $item) {
    if ($item[0] === $searchValue1 && $item[1] === $searchValue2 && $item[2] === $searchValue3) {
        print_r($item);
    }
}
```

A bit sophisticated version with checking whether `$searchValue_` is not empty is:

```
$searchValue1 = 'Dorado';
$searchValue2 = null;
$searchValue3 = 'Plastico';

foreach ($yourArray as $item) {
    if (
        (!empty($searchValue1) && $item[0] === $searchValue1)
        && 
        (!empty($searchValue2) && $item[1] === $searchValue2)
        &&
        (!empty($searchValue3) && $item[2] === $searchValue3)
    ) {
        print_r($item);
    }
}
```

**update**: with unknown number of search parameters you can:

```
$searchValues = ['Dorado', 'Plastico'];
foreach ($yourArray as $item) {
    // find intersection of two arrays
    $intersect = array_intersect($item, $searchValues);
    // if size of intersection is same as size of `$searchValues`
    // then you can be sure that all elements of `$searchValues` are in `$item`
    if (count($intersect) === count($searchValues)) {
        print_r($item);
    }
}
```

Comment: its close, but the initial values are dynamic, variable the number of them, i recieve each variable name with order with:

foreach ($arrOpciones as $itemOpcion => $valOpcion) {
        echo " $valOpcion";
    }

Comment: __Updated__ my answer.